# Php SimpleXMLElemenet not working

Tags: php, xml

i have this following line of code

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElemenet($content);
```

but im getting this error

Fatal error: Class 'SimpleXMLElemenet' not found in

I have checked phpinfo and simpleXML is enabled.

Any ideas in how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: `SimpleXMLElemenet` typo -> `SimpleXMLElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spell "Element" correctly. It only has 7 letters in it.